# EBS not redirecting to magento website after payment, shows 503 error

Tags: magento, redirect, payment-gateway

I have this strange problem. I have integrated EBS payment gateway with magento website. When the user checks out using the credit/debit card option , he is redirected to payment gateway. after the success/failure of the payment, it keeps loading and returns an error saying service not available with 503 Error. I am still trying to figure it out. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you check the return back URL? May be you missing index.php ig yes then enable rewrite mode

Comment: Hi, I am pretty new to magento, could you guide me through it?

Comment: give me url of website

Comment: www.confidentialcouture.com/index.php/

Comment: Hey, add me on skype if you have an account on it. i could really use your help. I am stuck with this since friday. my id is rick.thakur